# UITabBarController inside UITabBarController in ios using storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

There are 3 Tabs inside "View Controller "A" and 2 tabs inside "View Controller "B".

Both View controllers are embedded inside UITabBarControllers.

When I click on a particular tab in "A" I want to load View "B" and have it display its own UITabBar with its own tabs and not the UITabBar pushed by A.

I tried using storyboard, but application is crashing.

Comment: First i want to know can i achieve this in ios? Tabs inside particular tab?

Comment: Post your error message, so that we can understand what you have done so far.

Comment: yes, you can achieve this by creating TabBarController inside a controller.

Comment: @user3291667- have you seen my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add 1 TabbarViewController In StoryBoard and then Remove onviewController from two subViewControllers.

And then Add another TabbarViewController and attached this TabbarViewController as viewControllers of first TabbarViewController.

[image]

Using this way you can do

A --> UITabBarController with 3 tabs

B --> UITabBarController with 2 tabs

[image]

Comment: Hi man i tried your example. But it is not loading B when i click on second tab bar item in A. Whether i should write any action, when i click on second tab bar item present in A to B?

Comment: Please try my updated image chnages

Comment: Whether it is moving to B when i click on second tab bar item in A. I am not getting any changes you made for above image

Comment: Thank you very much man.One more question.Tab Items present in B are sitting on top of Tab items of A when i move to B.Can i hide Tab items of A, when i move to B?

Comment: Thank you very much man.One more question.Tab Items present in B are sitting on top of Tab items of A when i move to B.Can i hide Tab items of A, when i move to B? Link:http://i.stack.imgur.com/2tLh4.png

Comment: I tried the above answer the 2nd and third view controller are showing the bar of first tab bar how to hide it ??

Comment: I have not try it but you can use this in code in 2nd and 3rd 

self.tabBarController.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = TRUE

And again show when first appears.

Comment: Thanks man worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Taken from Apple's documentation on `UITabBarController`:

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

So this means Apple doesn't officially support doing this. It happens that you can do tricks to get it to work, but it could easily break at any time. In fact it's now harder than it used to be to get it to work because of changes that Apple made. It also is somewhat poor UI design to have nested tab bar controllers like this.

If you wish to have multiple `UITabBar`s without risking this, you can use the `UITabBar` directly. You could either have one `UITabBarController` for the "outer" tab bar and use a `UITabBar` directly for the inner one, or you could just use two `UITabBar`s in the first place. You have to implement the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol to mimic the behavior of a `UITabBarController`, as well as set up your view controller to do your own view controller containment. This approach would give you the best future-proofing, because it would be unlikely to break with a future iOS update.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you want something like this then you can download it from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5T2z28ShqrFc1dtaFlkNmtldEE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for your answer man.How can i achieve the same thing, without using ViewController between One TabBarController and another TabBarController?

Comment: how did u do that?when i did this,The second UITabBarController is missing.when going on push segue,Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889901/uitabbarcontroller-push-segue-to-another-uitabbarcontroller

Comment: @6245Htarwara- check the source code in answer